# Not able to wrap values in quotes when exporting CQL table to CSV

Tags: csv, cassandra, copy

I am not able to copy data into a CSV file and have them wrapped with single quotes:

e.g.

**Table**: myks.mytable

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 |

command used: `copy myks.mytable (column1,column2) to 'myfile.csv' WITH HEADER=FALSE AND DELIMITER=';' AND QUOTE='"';`

**expected result:**

The CSV file to have one row: `"value1";"value2"`

**actual result:**

The CSV file has one row: `value1:value2`

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with the cqlsh `COPY` command where it doesn't seem to honour the `QUOTE` option.

I would suggest you [report it here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/CreateIssue.jspa?pid=12310865) so it can be triaged and fixed as appropriate. Cheers!

Comment: I Opened a defect.